# error: invalid command 'bdist_egg'

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py, egg

I am running:

Ubuntu 13.04

Python 2.7.4

I am trying this [very simple tutorial](http://www.mxm.dk/2008/02/python-eggs-simple-introduction.html) on making a python egg, but am having difficulties when I actually try to run the command to make the egg.

```
    <me>@<compname>:~/Desktop/SANDBOX/somedir$ python setup.py bdist_egg
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help

    error: invalid command 'bdist_egg'
```

What I know so far:
When I enter the command,

```
    $ python setup.py --help-commands
```

I get back all the normal commands, but not the ["extra commands"](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#using-setup-py). I have tried googling and searching Stack Overflow but have yet to yield any useful results. I understand I am most likely missing a dependency but I had believed I installed all required parts to make this work.

Any insight is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`bdist_egg` is a command supplied by `setuptools`. Make sure you import from that project in `setup.py`, *not* from `distutils`:

```
from setuptools import setup
```

The tutorial does tell you to do this, but it appears you missed that part.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.
I had the line

        "from distutils.core import setup"

by mistake, still leftover from the previous example they had. Many thanks.

Comment: The setup.py provided with pycrypto 2.6.1 did not have `bdist_egg` as a command. Adding the import line as above worked and I could build the egg file for it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue then I realized that I need too install the setuptools first, oops:

[Setup Tools Installation Instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions)